# SQL inner join same table to get max value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table "tblTrasaction". I used the following code to get the max date:

```
select Max(t.TranDate) from tblTrasaction
```

Then I want use the max date value to get the max transaction ID,I used the following code:

```
   select Max(t.TranDate) from tblTrasaction t
   inner join
   (
      select Max(t.TranID) from tblTrasaction t
   ) temp On temp.TranID =t.TranID
```

But FAIL to get the result, how to I fix it? Thanks

Comment: You've tagged this with mysql and sql-server (Microsoft SQL Server), I guess this should be just mysql?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it this way,

```
SELECT  MAX(TranID) TranID
FROM    tblTrasaction 
WHERE   TranDate = (SELECT MAX(TranDate) FROM tblTrasaction)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
select Max(t.TranID)
from tblTrasaction t
where t.TranDate in (select Max(t1.TranDate) from tblTrasaction t1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if I've missed something but wouldn't it be easier to do:

If the original poster is using mysql:

```
select t.TranDate from tblTrasaction t
order by t.TranDate desc, t.TranID desc
limit 1
```

If the original poster is using SQL-Server:

```
select top 1 t.TranDate from tblTrasaction t
order by t.TranDate desc, t.TranID desc
```